# Alternative to references in a GROUP BY column to the results of a correlated subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, correlated-subquery, amazon-redshift, paraccel

This question comes as a result of a limitation in Amazon Redshift, the columnar analytics database based on Paraccel. One of the unsupported features is [references in a GROUP BY column to the results of a correlated subquery](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html).

For example, the following statement will generate a Redshift error because GROUP BY uses `list` which is generated by a subquery.

```
select listing.listid,
(select count (sales.listid) from sales where sales.listid=listing.listid) as list
from listing
group by list, listing.listid;
```

The following example from [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) is another unsupported use case (an answer to a [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819183/group-by-restricted-count-in-amazon-redshift-postgresql) that generated this general question).

```
select type, (case when cnt > XXX then url end) as url, sum(cnt) as visit_cnt
from (select type, url, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by type, url
     ) t
group by type, url
order by type, sum(cnt) desc;
```

The purpose of this question is to find a generic pattern for overcoming this particular Amazon Redshift correlated subquery limitation. What are the alternative SQL patterns for achieving the same outcome as using values from correlated subqueries?

Comment: For folks unfamiliar with Redshift: Assume you're working with roughly a PostgreSQL 8.1/8.2 feature set, plus a few extra features and extra limitations. No CTEs or window functions, no `unnest` and `array_agg`, etc. (BTW, it'd be great if there was a Redshift SQLFiddle).

Comment: You do have Window functions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html

Comment: +1 @Guy: there are indeed window functions. They do have limitations, though.

Answer (score 1):

A left join should do the trick, unless I'm missing something.

```
SELECT listing.listid
      ,COUNT(sales.listid)
FROM      listing
LEFT JOIN sales
       ON sales.listid = listing.listid
GROUP BY listing.listid
ORDER BY COUNT(sales.listid) DESC
;
```